# MessageKit won't build when integrating into app

Tags: objective-c, swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller, xcode10.2, messagekit

I'm trying integrate MessageKit with my project. I'm getting 3 errors when attempting to build:
1. Header 'MessageKit-Swift.h' not found
2. :0: error: could not build Objective-C module 'MessageKit'
3. No such module 'InputBarAccessoryView'

I've cleaned the project prior to build (several times). I've also tried several versions of MessageKit. I've also changed my Swift version from 4.0 to 4.2 to 5 and am receiving the same errors.

Here is my PodFile

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target '####' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for #####
  pod 'MessageKit',          '~> 3.0.0'
  pod 'MessageInputBar',     '~> 0.4.1'
pod 'InputBarAccessoryView'

end
```

Comment: do you open the project or workspace file?

Comment: @andrey I open the workspace